# Robotidy configuration file that disables long-line-wrapping

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm using robotidy but I haven't quite managed to wrap my head around how I'm supposed to tell robotidy to not wrap long-lines.

I have tried the following in the robotidy.toml:

```
  [tool.robotidy]
  transform = [
     "SplitTooLongLine:line_length=9999"
  ]
```

Unfortunately even though this does indeed disable long-line-wrapping it also disables all other kinds of transformations as well which is obviously not the intended effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways of configuring the transformers in robotidy.

1. `--transform` - like you noticed - will select and run only transformers listed using `--transform` option. You can optionally pass configuration through `--transform` option. Not suitable for your case because you want to run rest of the transformers.
2. `--configure` - pass configuration to your transformer:

```
  [tool.robotidy]
  configure = [
     "SplitTooLongLine:line_length=9999"
  ]
```

It will run all default transformers and additionaly configure SplitTooLongLine with line_length parameter 9999.

Hovewer I think it would be better to disable SplitTooLong altogether since you don't want to run it - you can use `enabled` parameter for that:

```
[tool.robotidy]
configure = [
    "SplitTooLongLine:enabled=False"
]
```

It's described in the docs (I admit though I should link it better, for example in every transformer provide url to this page): https://robotidy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/configuring_transformers.html#configuring-transformers

Comment: Just a note that there could be transformers that are disabled by default and could be enabled by using enabled=True configuration.  An example of such transformers is: https://robotidy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transformers/RenameTestCases.html or https://robotidy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transformers/NormalizeTags.html